# SQLAlchemy insert select query from case statement to FROM clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have case statement saved in variable like:

```
article_video_exists = exists(
    select([1], correlate=False, from_obj=article_video_t).where(
        article_video_t.c.article_id == article_t.c.id))

has_videos_case = case([(article_video_exists, 1), ], else_=0).label(
    'has_videos')
```

And use this case like

```
select([has_videos_case], from_obj=article_t)
```

After executing, i saw in query FROM statement like

```
FROM article_t, 
     (select 1 
      from article_video_t 
      where article_video_t.article_id=article_t.id)
```

and error that i should use alias. 
I tried use alias for select in case, but it's not fixed my problem. 
I tried pass correlate=False to all select clauses, but it's not help, but if i pass case as is in final select clause without using variable, it's work and not generate invalid FROM clause.

But after this i have many duplicating code, so how use variable for case in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if you the error is related to the code that you show, because i would expect to see `EXISTS` somewhere in your expression, and I do not.

Comment: i show just FROM clause, without select. select clause is correct with exists and correct table names. but FROM have this select subquery too and raise error with alias requirement

Comment: where is this *select subquery* coming from? another construct? please share more information

Comment: He is coming from select in exists: 
    select([1], correlate=False, from_obj=article_video_t).where(
            article_video_t.c.article_id == article_t.c.id)

He copy him as is and insert into FROM as from article_t, (select ....)

Answer (score 0):

fixed by using select(...).correlate_except(article_video_t).